# how to get text of div in php variable while its text come from js function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is my modal code

```
   <p id="getdatevalue" style="display:none;"></p> //HOW TO GET THIS DIV TEXT IN PHP

</div>
```

I am getting date of php in this anchor tag

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= $this->daysInCurrentMonth + $this->firstDayOfTheWeek; $i++) {
    ?><a href="#" id='<?php echo $dataVal; ?>' class="testclass">SetRecipe</a>
    <?php
    $day++;
}
?>
```

and opening modal window on click of this link

I am passing date as id in some div and getting same id when click on testclass , mean i am getting value of date suppose 27-04-2014 in id populated via lope

```
<script>
    $(".testclass").click(function(event) {
                    var date_value = $(this).attr("id");
                    $("#getdatevalue").html(date_value);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to generate a div text with PHP? Or you want the PHP server to get the contents of that div?

Comment: i want to save text of div in php variable ie when i open modal i get current data (id of that div) stored in php variable

Comment: In general what andrew said below in the answers - saving a client side value into a server variable. But you're probably better off doing ALL the client side calculation on client-side.

Answer (score 1):

using [jquery post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
<script>
    $(".testclass").click(function(event) {
                    var date_value = $(this).attr("id");
                    $("#getdatevalue").html(date_value);
                    $.post('aPhpFile.php',{
                      dateVal: $("#getdatevalue").html()
                       });
                   // since you specifically asked how to get the value from that
                   //  element, but $.post('aPhpFile.php',{dateVal:date_value});
                   // would be fine
              });
  </script>
```

and php (aPhpFile.php);

```
 <?php
 $postedVal = $_POST['dateVal'];
```